# How to add date picker to column in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have following code which creates column for epiration date in my Grid.php. Right now it takes data from DB field which is empty because I would like to have date picker in the column which will save picked date in DB and then show it back to admin. I know that it is possible to do it with `$fieldset` but I need to use `addColumn`

```
$this->addColumn('expiration_date', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('AdvancedStock')->__('Expiration Date'),
            'index' => $this['expiration_date'],
            'type' => 'datetime',
    ));
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are getting this from: **$this['expiration_date']**

but that should work, try setting filer and sortable manually.

```
array(
    'index'     => 'fieldname',
    'filter'    => true,
    'sortable'  => true,
    'type'      => 'datetime',
)
```

You will also need to make sure you have included your fieldname in the collection query if it's a none-standard field you have added, by modifying the _prepareCollection() method.

This will be slightly different depending on the collection model you are using

```
$collection->addFieldToSelect('fieldname');
```

Comment: This method is to get date from DB but I need to have date picker in the column

Answer (score 0):

Instead of type => 'datetime' try type='date' . hope it helps. 
You have to add

```
  <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js_css</type>
            <name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name>
            <params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>-->
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>-->
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>-->
        </action>
    </reference>
```

in design/adminhtml/ .../layout, in your xml file corresponding your modified module.